Where did the Chofetz Chaim mention a segula for Refuah in connection with Shabbos
Read in a pamphlet that the Chofetz Chaim says a segula for Refuah is to have challos and wine on table by daybreak Friday where is the source

https://matzav.com/a-real-segulah-from-the-chofetz-chaim/

Welcome to MiYodeya Chava and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!
